# Does Apple's M7 Processor support low-power GPS tracking?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, core-motion, apple-m7

Apple's new M7 co-processor is said to enable a new generation of health and fitness apps by providing continuous monitoring of movement without draining the battery.

At the iPhone 5S announcement, Apple listed support for these sensors:

> - Accelerometer
> - Gyroscope
> - Compass

It doesn't mention GPS hardware, but because it would make sense for me, I'd like to know if the M7 processor can also be used for low-power geo-location tracking?

Answer (score 1):

The low power option is to specify that the location manager can use deferred updates. When you do this the GPS hardware (where supported) will maintain a cache of updates until it's buffer is full (or your specified max distance is exceeded) and then send a block of updates to your app in one set (saving power by not activating the app frequently).

Comment: Thats interesting.. Can you please provide a link where i can find more info on this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html discusses in general. One of the recent WWDC videos also covered the topic. @akash

Answer (score 0):

M7 Coprocessor would not be helpful in anyway to track the location. But some apps like STRAVA run is using M7 data to monitor the motion activity and start the GPS when the motion is detected. Which is great to save the battery.